# How can I calculate the penetration depth between two colliding 3D AABBs?

Tags: c#, collision-detection, physics, collision-resolution

I'm currently working on implementing a very basic collision system in my game at the moment that only uses 3D AABBs. My AABB `struct` currently looks like this at the moment.

```
/// <summary>
/// This struct represents a 3-dimensional bounding box that is aligned
/// to the three world axes.
/// </summary>
public struct AxisAlignedBB
{
    public Vector3 Position { get; set; }
    public Vector3 HalfScale { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor for the AxisAlignedBB struct.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="position">The position of the AABB.</param>
    /// <param name="halfScale">The half scale of the AABB.</param>
    public AxisAlignedBB(Vector3 position, Vector3 halfScale)
    {
        this.Position = position;
        this.HalfScale = halfScale;
    }
}
```

I'm stuck on how the penetration depth between two different colliding AABBs with the AABB format I've laid out in the `struct` above is calculated. I've spent hours trying to come up with and look for a solution to this but I just can't seem to find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a method to find the penetration depth between two axis aligned bounding boxes at low velocities.

I've commented the code to explain how it works.

```
public static bool AABBAABB(AABB a, AABB b, ref Contact contact)
{
    // Minimum Translation Vector
    // ==========================
    float mtvDistance = float.MaxValue;             // Set current minimum distance (max float value so next value is always less)
    Vector3 mtvAxis = new Vector3();                // Axis along which to travel with the minimum distance

    // Axes of potential separation
    // ============================
    // - Each shape must be projected on these axes to test for intersection:
    //          
    // (1, 0, 0)                    A0 (= B0) [X Axis]
    // (0, 1, 0)                    A1 (= B1) [Y Axis]
    // (0, 0, 1)                    A1 (= B2) [Z Axis]

    // [X Axis]
    if (!TestAxisStatic(Vector3.UnitX, a.MinPoint.X, a.MaxPoint.X, b.MinPoint.X, b.MaxPoint.X, ref mtvAxis, ref mtvDistance))
        return false;

    // [Y Axis]
    if (!TestAxisStatic(Vector3.UnitY, a.MinPoint.Y, a.MaxPoint.Y, b.MinPoint.Y, b.MaxPoint.Y, ref mtvAxis, ref mtvDistance))
        return false;

    // [Z Axis]
    if (!TestAxisStatic(Vector3.UnitZ, a.MinPoint.Z, a.MaxPoint.Z, b.MinPoint.Z, b.MaxPoint.Z, ref mtvAxis, ref mtvDistance))
        return false;

    contact.isIntersecting = true;

    // Calculate Minimum Translation Vector (MTV) [normal * penetration]
    contact.nEnter = Vector3.Normalize(mtvAxis);

    // Multiply the penetration depth by itself plus a small increment
    // When the penetration is resolved using the MTV, it will no longer intersect
    contact.penetration = (float)Math.Sqrt(mtvDistance) * 1.001f;

    return true;
}

private static bool TestAxisStatic(Vector3 axis, float minA, float maxA, float minB, float maxB, ref Vector3 mtvAxis, ref float mtvDistance)
{
    // Separating Axis Theorem
    // =======================
    // - Two convex shapes only overlap if they overlap on all axes of separation
    // - In order to create accurate responses we need to find the collision vector (Minimum Translation Vector)   
    // - The collision vector is made from a vector and a scalar, 
    //   - The vector value is the axis associated with the smallest penetration
    //   - The scalar value is the smallest penetration value
    // - Find if the two boxes intersect along a single axis
    // - Compute the intersection interval for that axis
    // - Keep the smallest intersection/penetration value
    float axisLengthSquared = Vector3.Dot(axis, axis);

    // If the axis is degenerate then ignore
    if (axisLengthSquared < 1.0e-8f)
        return true;

    // Calculate the two possible overlap ranges
    // Either we overlap on the left or the right sides
    float d0 = (maxB - minA);   // 'Left' side
    float d1 = (maxA - minB);   // 'Right' side

    // Intervals do not overlap, so no intersection
    if (d0 <= 0.0f || d1 <= 0.0f)
        return false;

    // Find out if we overlap on the 'right' or 'left' of the object.
    float overlap = (d0 < d1) ? d0 : -d1;

    // The mtd vector for that axis
    Vector3 sep = axis * (overlap / axisLengthSquared);

    // The mtd vector length squared
    float sepLengthSquared = Vector3.Dot(sep, sep);

    // If that vector is smaller than our computed Minimum Translation Distance use that vector as our current MTV distance
    if (sepLengthSquared < mtvDistance)
    {
        mtvDistance = sepLengthSquared;
        mtvAxis = sep;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain why it will not work with the AABB format you've laid out?  You can find the MinPoint and MaxPoint using Position - HalfScale and Position + HalfScale.  If SAT seems unnecessary then you should be more clear about what you would like.  GJK perhaps?

Comment: Ah, I see how I can use my format. Sorry about that. I do still feel SAT is unnecessary for simple AABB-AABB collision though.

Comment: Okay, so this method works quite well, with no major issues, however, I still feel like SAT is unnecessary for simple AABB-AABB collision. Isn't there an AABB-AABB specific collision detection and resolution method?

Comment: Not that I know of.

However, here are some books that I would recommend you read: [Real-time Collision Detection][1] and [Geometric Tools for Computer Graphics][2].  If you wish to see what is used in a real-time 3D physics engine for collision detection and response then I would highly recommend taking a look at the [BEPU source code][3].  It is written in C# and fairly easy to follow.


  [1]: http://realtimecollisiondetection.net/
  [2]: https://www.geometrictools.com/Books/GeometricTools/AboutTheBook.html
  [3]: https://bepuphysics.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest